# Optimal Covered Call Strategy

Tags: options, option-strategies

How do I compute the optimal strike / expiry / when to close or roll for a covered call strategy on a highly liquid underlying (e.g. SPY)?

Comment: What are some of the trade-offs that you see or goals that you are trying to meet.

Comment: maximize profit at lowest risk :-)

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, there is no "objectively" optimal strategy, and it depends on your goals and risk tolerance.

I personally like to sell covered calls on a weekly schedule, for calls that expire the week after. Of course, the collected credit is lower than with expiration dates further in the future, but it gives me more flexibility. I can let them expire (worthless, hopefully) and then decide from scratch, possibly at a different strike price.

As for the strike price, I set it high enough that I wouldn't mind having to sell, but not higher.

I use it for stocks I bought as an investment (not  a short-term trade), but only for stocks I feel I want to keep for a few weeks to months, and not for the ones that I want to keep for decades.